How to count non-zero, non-NA values in dataframe
So my question is a bit like the one posted here: Count the number of non-zero elements of each column, but I also have NAs in my data.frame. I would like to count the number of non-zero, non-NA values in each column.
Data
x <- cbind(x1 = NA, x2 = c(4:1), x3 = c(0, NA, 1, NA))

Desired Result
[1] 0 4 1


colSums is probably the simplest way to to this.
x <- cbind(x1 = NA, x2 = c(4:1), x3 = c(0, NA, 1, NA))
colSums(x != 0, na.rm = TRUE)
#> x1 x2 x3 
#> 0  4  1 

As the name implies, colSums computes column sums. The argument na.rm = TRUE means that NA values are ignored during the computation. x != 0 creates a matrix where numeric values are replaced by TRUE (if the original values is not 0) and FALSE (if the original values is 0). colSums then treats TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0, so the sum for each column becomes the number of non-zero elements.

"x != 0 creates a data frame" is wrong. cbind() creates a matrix here. x != 0 returns a matrix. The method cbind.data.frame() would return a data.frame, which in turn would be coerced to class matrix by x != 0.

As you said your object is a data frame, if your data is large you may want to avoid matrix functions like colSums(). The source contains the line:
if(is.data.frame(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)

This means the entirety of your data will be copied into a matrix. This may be slow. Also if you have different data types they'll all be coerced to the same type.
I decided to try the two answers as well as another one using a data frame as input. I decided to run another one, using vapply():
vapply(
    x_df,
    \(x) sum(x != 0, na.rm = TRUE),
    integer(1)
)
# x1 x2 x3 
#  0  4  1 

I simulated some data with up to 1m rows and 100k columns. colSums() is faster than apply() but vapply() is consistently faster than both, regardless of the size of the data:

Speed may not matter in your case and your data may be all of the same type, in which case I think the colSums() approach is more readable. However, these are issues worth being aware of.
Benchmark code
results <- bench::press(
    n_rows  = 10^(1:6),
    n_cols = 10^(1:5),
    {
        get_vals  <- \(n, vals = c(0:9, NA_integer_)) sample(vals, n, replace = TRUE)
        x <- data.frame(lapply(n_cols, \(.) get_vals(n_rows)))
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            max_iterations = 100,
            relative = TRUE,
            apply = {
                apply(x, 2, \(z) sum(z!=0, na.rm = TRUE))
            },
            colSums = {
                colSums(x != 0, na.rm = TRUE)
            },
            vapply = {
                vapply(x,\(x) sum(x != 0, na.rm = TRUE),integer(1))
            }
        )
    }
)

# Output:
# # A tibble: 90 × 9
#    expression  n_rows n_cols   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr
#    <bch:expr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#  1 apply           10     10  8.32   7.35      1          NaN   NaN      100
#  2 colSums         10     10  4.21   3.82      1.85       NaN   NaN      100
#  3 vapply          10     10  1      1         6.31       NaN   NaN      100
#  4 apply          100     10  5.99   6.32      1            5   NaN      100
#  5 colSums        100     10  3.57   3.70      1.72         3   NaN      100
#  6 vapply         100     10  1      1         5.15         1   NaN      100
#  7 apply         1000     10  7.07   6.49      1            5   NaN      100
#  8 colSums       1000     10  3.66   3.17      2.24         3   NaN      100
#  9 vapply        1000     10  1      1         7.13         1   NaN      100
# 10 apply        10000     10  4.31   4.14      1            5   NaN      100
# 11 colSums      10000     10  2.57   2.20      1.84         3   NaN      100
# 12 vapply       10000     10  1      1         4.01         1   NaN      100
# 13 apply       100000     10  3.26   3.01      1            5     1.33    96
# 14 colSums     100000     10  1.73   1.66      1.72         3     1.12    98
# 15 vapply      100000     10  1      1         3.10         1     1       99
# 16 apply      1000000     10  3.41   2.89      1            5     6.65    13
# 17 colSums    1000000     10  1.82   1.59      1.75         3     4.20    36
# 18 vapply     1000000     10  1      1         2.71         1     1       78
# 19 apply           10    100  5.73   6.43      1          NaN   NaN      100
# 20 colSums         10    100  3.62   3.98      1.78       NaN   NaN      100
# 21 vapply          10    100  1      1         6.84       NaN   NaN      100
# 22 apply          100    100  6.54   6.63      1            5   NaN      100
# 23 colSums        100    100  4.88   4.19      1.54         3   NaN      100
# 24 vapply         100    100  1      1         5.96         1   NaN      100
# 25 apply         1000    100  5.90   5.67      1            5   NaN      100
# 26 colSums       1000    100  3.99   3.29      1.83         3   NaN      100
# 27 vapply        1000    100  1      1         5.02         1   NaN      100
# 28 apply        10000    100  5.41   3.88      1            5   Inf       99
# 29 colSums      10000    100  3.08   2.20      2.10         3   NaN      100
# 30 vapply       10000    100  1      1         5.20         1   NaN      100
# 31 apply       100000    100  2.90   3.12      1            5     1.65    97
# 32 colSums     100000    100  2.23   1.71      1.86         3     1       99
# 33 vapply      100000    100  1      1         3.30         1     1.78    99
# 34 apply      1000000    100  3.78   2.91      1            5     3.84    15
# 35 colSums    1000000    100  2.04   1.63      1.83         3     3.20    36
# 36 vapply     1000000    100  1      1         2.98         1     1       78
# 37 apply           10   1000  5.68   6.56      1          NaN   NaN      100
# 38 colSums         10   1000  3.27   3.34      1.96       NaN   NaN      100
# 39 vapply          10   1000  1      1         6.81       NaN   NaN      100
# 40 apply          100   1000  4.47   6.97      1            5   NaN      100
# 41 colSums        100   1000  3.68   3.76      1.40         3   NaN      100
# 42 vapply         100   1000  1      1         7.93         1   NaN      100
# 43 apply         1000   1000  6.64   6.53      1            5   NaN      100
# 44 colSums       1000   1000  3.83   4.06      1.44         3   NaN      100
# 45 vapply        1000   1000  1      1         6.24         1   NaN      100
# 46 apply        10000   1000  3.56   3.97      1            5   NaN      100
# 47 colSums      10000   1000  1.44   2.18      1.90         3   NaN      100
# 48 vapply       10000   1000  1      1         3.18         1   Inf       99
# 49 apply       100000   1000  4.07   3.06      1            5   Inf       97
# 50 colSums     100000   1000  2.38   1.86      1.59         3   Inf       98
# 51 vapply      100000   1000  1      1         3.29         1   NaN      100
# 52 apply      1000000   1000  3.51   3.09      1            5     3.65    14
# 53 colSums    1000000   1000  1.83   1.67      1.86         3     3.09    37
# 54 vapply     1000000   1000  1      1         3.17         1     1       81
# 55 apply           10  10000  4.55   6.84      1          NaN   NaN      100
# 56 colSums         10  10000  3.75   3.94      1.86       NaN   NaN      100
# 57 vapply          10  10000  1      1         6.68       NaN   NaN      100
# 58 apply          100  10000  6.30  11.5       1            5   NaN      100
# 59 colSums        100  10000  3.68   3.77      2.25         3   NaN      100
# 60 vapply         100  10000  1      1         9.80         1   NaN      100
# 61 apply         1000  10000  3.44   3.58      1            5   NaN      100
# 62 colSums       1000  10000  1.98   3.5       1.55         3   NaN      100
# 63 vapply        1000  10000  1      1         5.16         1   NaN      100
# 64 apply        10000  10000  2.56   3.63      1            5   NaN      100
# 65 colSums      10000  10000  2.23   2.27      1.65         3   NaN      100
# 66 vapply       10000  10000  1      1         3.28         1   NaN      100
# 67 apply       100000  10000  2.10   2.85      1            5   Inf       97
# 68 colSums     100000  10000  1.35   1.66      1.47         3   Inf       98
# 69 vapply      100000  10000  1      1         2.59         1   NaN      100
# 70 apply      1000000  10000  3.11   3.08      1            5     3.81    15
# 71 colSums    1000000  10000  1.60   1.62      1.86         3     3.32    32
# 72 vapply     1000000  10000  1      1         2.97         1     1       77
# 73 apply           10 100000  6.31   5.46      1          NaN   NaN      100
# 74 colSums         10 100000  3.81   3.30      1.67       NaN   NaN      100
# 75 vapply          10 100000  1      1         5.89       NaN   NaN      100
# 76 apply          100 100000  7      6.97      1            5   NaN      100
# 77 colSums        100 100000  4.37   3.69      2.45         3   NaN      100
# 78 vapply         100 100000  1      1         8.91         1   NaN      100
# 79 apply         1000 100000  4.98   3.24      1            5   NaN      100
# 80 colSums       1000 100000  2.98   3.56      1.09         3   NaN      100
# 81 vapply        1000 100000  1      1         3.41         1   NaN      100
# 82 apply        10000 100000  3.70   5.12      1            5   NaN      100
# 83 colSums      10000 100000  2.16   2.84      1.64         3   NaN      100
# 84 vapply       10000 100000  1      1         3.57         1   NaN      100
# 85 apply       100000 100000  2.35   2.77      1            5     1.19    97
# 86 colSums     100000 100000  1.54   1.60      1.68         3     1.31    98
# 87 vapply      100000 100000  1      1         2.58         1     1       99
# 88 apply      1000000 100000  3.96   2.88      1            5     2.43    18
# 89 colSums    1000000 100000  2.05   1.64      1.71         3     2.65    34
# 90 vapply     1000000 100000  1      1         2.89         1     1       76

# Plotting code

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(results, type = "ridge") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 13) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_blank())


Not too sure. OP mentions data.frame, but provides (unintentionally?) a matrix object as toy data. vapply() is almost always the best choice imo (+1).

@Friede thanks yeah I assumed it was unintentional as the question title and text both say data frame and, while matrices are not exactly rare, data frames are a more common data structure at least in terms of R SO questions.

Would have thought collapse::fsum(x != 0) (na.rm=TRUE is default), which seems to have methods for both, is faster then, but no.

@Friede interesting it's not faster at all - I thought it might be slightly. I doubt that libraries will provide any significant speed up of base sum() run on entire columns. However once you introduce some sort of group by, I'm sure collapse and data.table will be quite a bit faster.

You could sum them but use na.rm = TRUE as argument to not including the NA in your summation like this:
x <- cbind(x1 = NA, x2 = c(4:1), x3 = c(0, NA, 1, NA))
apply(x, 2, \(z) sum(z!=0, na.rm = TRUE))
#> x1 x2 x3 
#>  0  4  1

Created on 2024-05-13 with reprex v2.1.0
